# Carregar input text após selecionar select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

Eu tenho um select que está sendo populado via ajax, ao abrir o modal, eu chamo a função que carrega o select, e está funcionando perfeitamente.

Porém eu preciso um efeito tipo cascata, no primeiro campo, e ao mudar, ele alterar o input text conforme o campo selecionado. 
Como posso fazer? 
Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
function Carrega(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/PessoasServicos/CarregaDados",
        data: { id },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var tipoplano = $('#txtTipoPlano');
            tipoplano = data.resultado;
        }
    });
}

$('#cbplanos').on("click", function () {
    Carrega(1);
});
```

Estou passando o id 1 direto, para fazer um teste,
e aqui é o controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CarregaDados(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var resultado = (from a in _context.PlanosServicos
                          where a.Id == id
                          select new
                          {
                              a.Tipo,
                          });

            return Json(resultado);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Porém ele não me retorna erro, mas também não me retorna o que eu preciso.

Comment: Não ficou muito claro, você deseja após selecionar algum item do `select` mudar o texto de um `input`?

Comment: @Barbetta editei de como estou tentando fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editei o método `Carrega` passando o `id` para o `data` e jogo o retorno dentro do `input`

```
function Carrega(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/PessoasServicos/CarregaDados",
        data: { id: id },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#txtTipoPlano").val(data.tipo)
        }
    });
}
```

Tente user chamar o evento diretamente no `select`, ficaria assim:

```
<select id="cbplanos" onchange="Carrega(this.value)"></select>
```

Por fim, como está selecionando apenas um item, joguei esse valor para uma variável  e ai sim retornei um novo `json` com o campo `tipo`

```
public ActionResult CarregaDados(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var resultado = _context.PlanosServicos.Where(p=> p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault().Tipo;

        return Json(new { tipo = resultado});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz exatamente desta forma, porém o valor que o id recebe, é 0. Ele não está pegando o id selecionado.

Comment: Alterei, tente chamar diretamente no `select` a `function`

Comment: Vou tentar, porém verificando ele está entrando no catch no controller, retornando este erro "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
Mesmo alterando para chamar no select, ocorre o mesmo problema.

Comment: Está chegando algum Id na action?

Comment: Na action chega 0, mas na função carrega() ele chega certo.

Comment: Achei o problema rs, estava como post, alterei para get, e funcionou, porém o primeiro valor não vem selecionado, apenas se eu mudar no select.

Comment: aaah sim. Consigo Pensar em duas opções para o caso do primeiro valor; 1) Adiciona uma opção "Selecione" 2) na `function` que carrega o `select`, após carregar todos itens, chama o método Carrega passando como parâmetro o value do item selecionado.

Comment: Aliás, como eu pego o primeiro valor do select após incluir por ajax, ai eu posso chamar esta função logo em seguida.

Comment: Pode fazer assim `var selecionado =  $("#cbplanos option:selected").val();` - De uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106698/88361)

Comment: Deu certinho, obrigado.